# Trying to replace a Trailer's kitchen faucet

Tags: faucet

basically my issue here is I'm trying to replace the faucet in my trailer's kitchen but I've run into a problem here that I can't figure out how to solve.

[image]

[image]

This is what the end of my shut off valve looks like, and where the previous faucet connected.  It used to have tabs on it to help it twist, but they've broken off.

But this is what the new faucet's end looks like, and they don't fit. 
[image]

It looks on the inside of the first one that they could connect, if I could take off the big grey part, but it doesn't seem to disconnect at all.  I know absolutely nothing about this stuff so any help would be appreciated.  Do I need to buy some sort of adapter?  Or are they completely incompatible and I wasted my time?

Answer (score 1):

Your hose connections appear to be a ½” MIP on the stop-valve end (left side) and a 3/8” Male Compression fitting on the faucet.  An adapter is needed to make the connections. 
An appropriate connection can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JQ78LV3)  
Picture of the adapter is provided below.  You have to remove the nut on the 3/8” side to expose the threads.

[image: Pic]

This picture shows how it all goes together.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a 3/8 to 1/2” male to male adapter take the larger piece to a plumbing or big box store to make sure you get the right sizes but you will will need a 1/2” nipple a 3/8 nipple and a female reducer from 1/2” to 3/8 and some pipe dope or Teflon tape to make the transition. You may be able to get push on fittings also but the nipples may be cheaper and quick.

Answer (score 0):

Your stop-valve has 1/2"M.I.P. (male iron pipe) threads, your flex supply line is 3/8 female compression thread. An adapter that you can screw onto the stop valve could be cobbled together with various parts, or a single/simple adapter would work:

[image]

Even better, You could change out the stop-valve for one with 3/8 compression thread, but we would need to know how the valve attaches to the wall supply to advise you on that...